# error: disk 'hd,3' not found

Tags: grub2, bios, error-handling, boot-menu

Im on "GNU GRUB version 2.06"
When i click "Alternate USB Boot" this `error: disk 'hd,3' not found` comes up.

Inside (press e to edit the commans before booting)

`setparms 'FydeOS image A' linux /syslinux/vmlinuz.A init=/sbin/init boot=local rootwait ro noresume noswap loglevel=7 noinitrd audit=0 console=  i915.modeset=1 cros_efi cros_debug\ root=PARTUUID=BB5089A3-5293-044F-BB38-0627139767FE`

Comment: `disk 'hd,3' not found` indicates GRUB is trying to find the 4th partition on whatever disk it was booted from, and failing. "Alternate USB boot" suggests you are trying to boot from USB media, and the [FydeOS FAQ](https://fydeos.io/faq/why-is-my-usb-drive-divided-into-more-than-a-dozen-partitions-after-flashing-fydeos-image/) says that a properly prepared FydeOS USB boot media should have a large number of partitions; are you sure you prepared the boot media correctly?